# Delete failed Windows Update folder containing req file

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11

After several failed updates to **Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 (KB2538242)** and **Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Service Pack 1 (KB2538243)**, I hid these updates that were blocking the installation of new updates.

However, each attempt to install these two updates creates a folder. I end up with 18 folders with names like *5f74e02898edc7e763fed5d36b3291e1* or *27c1ff01ba981e84ec05ad61fe703ae8*. I can't delete them because the folders contain a hidden file `$shtdwn$.req`. I've tried deleting it with PowerShell as administrator, changing the security attributes in the Property panel and using safe mode, but nothing works.

How do I delete a *.req* file?

System information: Windows 11 (22H2)

Comment: Provide the ACL on the file.

Comment: The file named `$shtdwn$.req` typically identifies a temporary folder of Windows Update, which might explain why it's so hard to delete. I suggest checking Windows Update, to see if some update is blocked or cannot complete.

Comment: @harrymc That's exactly it. As indicated in the initial message, these files come from two updates that never completed for an error I've never been able to figure out. Each time a try to install them, a new folder is created and the installing stays to 0%.

Comment: Have you tried the troubleshooter for Windows Update (*Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Additional troubleshooters*) ?

Comment: @harrymc yes nothing is found

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Also try chkdsk /f. I think it's a file associated with the Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool.